# UIViewController starting below navigation bar moves up after touch

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

My view (programmatically created) starts below the translucent navigation bar but slides into the desired position when the tableview is touched/scrolled.  My view hierarchy...

```
UINavigationController
-- UIViewController (Container)
---- UIPageViewController
------ UIViewController (Detail)
-------- UIImageView
-------- UITableView (with content offset)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! did you try disabling `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` in your view controller? maybe it's messing up with your inset code.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

Comment: @EliKohen That property is deprecated

Comment: so you're using iOS 11 and XCode 9? it has been deprecated for iOS 11 but if you're building for iOS 10 that still could be the problem.

Comment: @EliKohen That did it.  Submit as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The problem was on my Container View Controller, not the view with the table

Comment: I'm glad it helped! ;)  Posting answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a problem with UIViewController adjusting tableView insets. Usually when you manage your own insets on tables you should disable viewController from automatically adjusting it:

`automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets = false`

*Note that it's deprecated on iOS11 but for older iOS you should still keep an eye on it.